# Should we tell a child to say Thank you

Tags: teaching

Many parents tell their children to say "Thank you" and some parents prefer making an example by saying Thank you themselves.

I personally think telling a child to say Thank you may back fire as saying Thank you is artificially enforced.

What is the better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by artificially enforced -- that they are not being taught sincere gratitude, but rather blind compliance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Thank you" is social etiquette.  I teach my children how to have manners & thanking others who do something for you, a service, a gift, a kindness, is part of that etiquette.  I am not always thankful for what has been done, but I *am* thankful for the gesture, as no one generally *has* to show you a courtesy of any sort.  I also teach my children to say "hello" when spoken to (unless they have a bad vibe for some reason) to say please when making a request, to say pardon me *before* interrupting a conversation or physically maneuvering around a person.  These are social skills and teaching social skills can only *help* your children navigate the world a little easier.  If they are perceived as rude, it will make their lives harder for it.

That said, I teach my children to say thank you from the time they can talk and later I teach them about what it means to have a gracious spirit and to appreciate all things, from having a comfortable bed to enough food to eat and often with options we enjoy, and for the gestures of others, offered in kindness.  If you teach a child gratitude, you need not worry to "force" them to say thank you, but when young they might occasionally need a reminder of the appropriate polite response, which in my culture *is* "thank you".  I've never needed to demand my kids say it, but I also work on making sure they understand gratitude on the whole.  Having a grateful heart can only enrich your life and help you find a sense of contentment and happiness in all things.